# unhandled error in observeEvent in R

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

```
library(shiny)
fieldsAll <- c("name", "favourite_pkg", "used_shiny", "r_num_years", "os_type")
fieldsMandatory <- c("name", "favourite_pkg")
labelMandatory <- function(label) {
  tagList(
    label,
    span("*", class = "mandatory_star")
  )
}
epochTime <- function() {
  return(as.integer(Sys.time()))
}
humanTime <- function() {
  format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d-%H%M%OS")
}
saveData <- function(data) {
  fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv",
                      humanTime(),
                      digest::digest(data))

  write.csv(x = data, file = file.path(responsesDir, fileName),
            row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
}
loadData <- function() {
  files <- list.files(file.path(responsesDir), full.names = TRUE)
  data <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  #data <- dplyr::rbind_all(data)
  data <- do.call(rbind, data)
  data
}

responsesDir <- file.path("responses")

appCSS <-
  ".mandatory_star { color: red; }
   .shiny-input-container { margin-top: 25px; }
   #submit_msg { margin-left: 15px; }
   #error { color: red; }
   body { background: #fcfcfc; }
   #header { background: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; margin: -20px -15px 0; padding: 15px 15px 10px; }
  "
adminUsers <- c("admin", "prof")

share <- list(
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::inlineCSS(appCSS),
    title = "My Form with Shiny code",
    tags$head(
    ),

    div(id = "header",
      h1("My Form with Shiny code"),
      strong( 

      a("Sai Mahesh")
      )
    ),

    fluidRow(
      column(6,
        div(
          id = "form",

          textInput("name", labelMandatory("Name"), ""),
          textInput("favourite_pkg", labelMandatory("Favourite R package")),
          checkboxInput("used_shiny", "I've built a Shiny app in R before", FALSE),
          sliderInput("r_num_years", "Number of years using R", 0, 25, 2, ticks = FALSE),
          selectInput("os_type", "Operating system used most frequently",
                      c("",  "Windows", "Mac", "Linux")),
          actionButton("submit", "Submit", class = "btn-primary"),

          shinyjs::hidden(
            span(id = "submit_msg", "Submitting..."),
            div(id = "error",
                div(br(), tags$b("Error: "), span(id = "error_msg"))
            )
          )
        ),

        shinyjs::hidden(
          div(
            id = "thankyou_msg",
            h3("Thanks, your response was submitted successfully!"),
            actionLink("submit_another", "Submit another response")
          )
        )
      ),
      column(6,
        uiOutput("adminPanelContainer")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {


    observe({
      mandatoryFilled <-
        vapply(fieldsMandatory,
               function(x) {
                 !is.null(input[[x]]) && input[[x]] != ""
               },
               logical(1))
      mandatoryFilled <- all(mandatoryFilled)

      shinyjs::toggleState(id = "submit", condition = mandatoryFilled)
    })


    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fieldsAll, function(x) input[[x]])
      data <- c(data, timestamp = epochTime())
      data <- t(data)
      data
    })    


    observeEvent(input$submit, {


      shinyjs::disable("submit")
      shinyjs::show("submit_msg")
      shinyjs::hide("error")


      tryCatch({
        saveData(formData())
        shinyjs::reset("form")
        shinyjs::hide("form")
        shinyjs::show("thankyou_msg")
      },
      error = function(err) {
        shinyjs::html("error_msg", err$message)
        shinyjs::show(id = "error", anim = TRUE, animType = "fade")
      },
      finally = {
        shinyjs::enable("submit")
        shinyjs::hide("submit_msg")
      })
    })


    observeEvent(input$submit_another, {
      shinyjs::show("form")
      shinyjs::hide("thankyou_msg")
    })


    output$adminPanelContainer <- renderUI({
      if (!isAdmin()) return()

      div(
        id = "adminPanel",
        h2("Previous responses "),
        downloadButton("downloadBtn", "Download responses"), br(), br(),
        DT::dataTableOutput("responsesTable") 
      )
    })


    isAdmin <- reactive({
      is.null(session$user) || session$user %in% adminUsers
    })    


    output$responsesTable <- DT::renderDataTable(
      loadData(),
      rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(searching = FALSE, lengthChange = FALSE)
    )


    output$downloadBtn <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { 
        sprintf("mimic-google-form_%s.csv", humanTime())
        #sprintf("get_me_responses.csv", humanTime())
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(loadData(), file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )    
  }
)
```

I have created a form where the submit button is showing me an error. I am unable to submit the form. I have created five mandatory fields and after filling all these fields the submit button gets enabled and when submit button is pressed it need to show that the form is submitted.

Comment: Care to describe the error? I tried it, seems to work fine (once you fill out all the fields) except it can't open some file that it needs.

Comment: I am running in r studio where I get these error:Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open file 'responses/20170528-230748_294d29ccf99f43d45187faef4b545dc7.‌​csv': No such file or directory Warning: Unhandled error in observer: 'html' is not an exported object from :shinyjs' observeEvent(input$submit)

Comment: Please suggest me what should I do to get rid of this error

Comment: After filling out certain fields the submit button gets enabled but when after filling all the mandatory fields when i click on submit button it shows me the above error in R studio and the form is not getting submitted.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not finding the file as I mentioned. Find a copy of that file and install it. Or modify the program so that it initializes itself. If it is your program that should be very easy.

Comment: yea thanks Mike Wise.I got it.

Comment: But I am getting each response as a seperate csv file.please suggest me in getting all the responses in a single csv file.